# Upload a file along with other data to MySQL DB using AngularJS, REST,Hibernate

Tags: java, angularjs, rest

I'm trying to upload a file along with some other data(name, description,etc) to MySQL DB using AngularJS, REST(in middle layer) and Hibernate(DAO).

I've tried many solutions including creating my own `directive` but still I'm unable to do it.

And I'm not using `<form>` in my `jsp` to submit. Rather than that, I'm using `ng-click=submit()` at end.

**Doubts**:-

1. Data type of DTO and DAO objects for file type? (`byte[]` or `blob`).
2. How to bind file to a `$scope.data` where `data` contains all other information along with `file`?
3. `$http.post(url,$scope.data)`. how to access this in REST method.

`@Consumes(??)
Response function add(DTO object){
//CALL TO DAO AND RETURN RESPOSNE
}`

I've tried the code on this [webpage](http://shazwazza.com/post/Uploading-files-and-JSON-data-in-the-same-request-with-Angular-JS) but how to handle it via `REST` is still an issue?

**Better if you'ld post a basic code snippet for this**

Answer (score 0):

This is the way that I used im my project a year ago. You could try:

HTML:

```
<form id="signupform" name="signupform" ng-submit="createUser()">
  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="email" ng-model="regisUser.email" ng-minlength="3" required />

  <label for="username">Username</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="regisUser.username" required />

  //File upload
  <input type="file" name="file" required>

  <button id="btn-signup" type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

AngularJS controller:

```
// create new user
$scope.createUser = function(){
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("username", $scope.regisUser.username);
    formData.append("email", $scope.regisUser.email);
    formData.append("avatar", document.forms['signupform'].file.files[0]);

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/api/users',
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
        data: formData
        })
        .success(function(data, status) {   
            ...
        })
        .error(function(data, status){
            ...
        });
};
```

Note that `headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}` is very important. Don't forget it :)

Spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/users", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Response insert(@RequestParam String username, @RequestParam String email, @RequestParam(required = false) MultipartFile avatar) {
    // now you can get avatar as file that was uploaded from client.
}
```

I used this way to upload image and audio files. Hope with some snippets code above is useful.

Comment: Thanks for the snippet. I have used `FileReader` instead of `FormData` since I haven't used form in my html.